# How to test RBF on Testnet?

Tags: testnet, replace-by-fee

I'd like to do RBF testing on testnet. I'd like to simulate a transaction with too-low fees, aka "stuck" transaction, and then RBF it in various ways.

Problem is, all testnet transactions are added to the next block due to mostly-empty mempool and 1 sat/B fee rate.

Is there a clever way to create a transaction that sits in the testnet mempool, which can be later mined after RBF?

Didn't the developers of RBF test their code on testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 workarounds possible:

1. It takes few minutes for most of the transactions to be included in a block. So, you can prepare all the steps in advance and perform within couple of minutes before this transaction is confirmed.
2. Broadcast transactions with fee rate below 1 sat/vByte

Change Min Transaction Relay Fee in `bitcoin.conf` with `minrelaytxfee=0.00000001`

Either run multiple nodes on testnet with same configuration and add them using `addnode` or ignore this step.

Create a transaction with `createrawtransaction`, Enable RBF and specify fee rate below 1 sat/vByte with arguments `"replaceable" : true` and `"fee_rate" : 0.5` in `fundrawtransaction`

Sign the transaction with `signrawtransactionwithwallet`

Broadcast the transaction with `sendrawtransaction`

Check the transaction details using https://chain.so/testnet/btc

[image: sochain-explorer]

Bump fee: `bumpfee 42bb96fa5f5812cfd53695f679b69bccaf37fb4d49b78a650e05e0109d92f223`

```
{
  "txid": "bac13170082c79033d37767e9180d676b05044acf90e41b1a992f76eda97f14e",
  "origfee": 0.00000526,
  "fee": 0.00005616,
  "errors": [
  ]
}
```